# Assign string[] array field to another array field of same type c#

Tags: c#, web-services, dynamics-business-central

I have two classes defined in my solution

```
public class Registration {
    [...]
    public list<Account> Accounts {get; set;}
}

public class Account {
    [...]       
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

In the web service that I am consuming, the following class definitions are available

```
public partial class VendReg {
    [...]
    private Payment_Details[] requestDetailsField;
    
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute(IsNullable=false)]
    public Payment_Details[] RequestDetails {
        get {
            return this.requestDetailsField;
        }
        set {
            this.requestDetailsField = value;
        }
    }       
}


public partial class Payment_Details {
          
    private string bk_CodeField;
    
    private string bk_NameField;
    
    private string bk_AddressField;
                         
    public string Bk_Code {
        get {
            return this.bk_CodeField;
        }
        set {
            this.bk_CodeField = value;
        }
    }
    
    public string Bk_Name {
        get {
            return this.bk_NameField;
        }
        set {
            this.bk_NameField = value;
        }
    }
    
    public string Bk_Address {
        get {
            return this.bk_AddressField;
        }
        set {
            this.bk_AddressField = value;
        }
    }         
}
```

I want to assign Account to Request Details which is an array of Payment_Details. I tried this code below
`vendReg.RequestDetails = registration.Accounts.Cast<Payment_Details>().ToArray();`

> I got invalid cast exception: Unable to cast object of type 'Account' to type 'Payment_Details'

Please guide on what I am not doing right

Comment: Your error is saying your data is actually of type `Models.BankAccount`, but I don't see such a type in your post.

Comment: @gunr2171, I have updated the question. It is actually Account not BankAccount. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert this yourself (or you can look into things like Automapper)

```
vendReg.RequestDetails = registration.Accounts.Select(acc => 
   new Payment_Details {
      Bk_Code = acc.Code,
      Bk_Name = acc.Name,
      Bk_Address = acc.Address
   }).ToArray();
```

Comment: This worked like magic. Thanks a bunch. Do you know why my code did not work?

Comment: @hopeforall type casting in c# is only works if the actual type at runtime matches. E.g. if you have class `Animal` and then `Cat: Animal` and `Dog: Animal` you can have an array of `Animal[]` and take one and cast as `Cat` And if that animal is a dog, the cast will fail. But you can take either `Cat` or `Dog` and cast as `Animal`.

Now in your case, `Account` and `Payment_Details` are unrelated types, so CLR can't figure out what you want it to do.

Comment: I taught the two classes are of the same type. Thanks for the explanation though. Appreciate